# XAML - How do I create a DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames dynamically and play the storyboard with VB?

Tags: xaml, animation, storyboard, microsoft-metro

I have 3 polygons that I am trying to "light up" (changing opacity) based on dynamically code.  For instance, I have a long string of random numbers (021200112).  I'm trying to create a dynamic storyboard with keyframes.  I'm testing it with a single polygon and I am getting a target error.  Your help is appreciated!!!

The polygons are created in the XAML (named Poly1, Poly2, Poly3).

Here is my error when it tries to play the storyboard:

```
WinRT information: Cannot resolve TargetProperty 1 on specified object.
```

Here is my code to test the animation on poly1.

```
Public Sub PlayStoryboard()

    Dim myDoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames As New DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames()
    Dim myLinearDoubleKeyFrame As New LinearDoubleKeyFrame()
    Dim myLinearDoubleKeyFrame2 As New LinearDoubleKeyFrame()

    myLinearDoubleKeyFrame.Value = 0.2
    myLinearDoubleKeyFrame.KeyTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)

    myLinearDoubleKeyFrame2.Value = 1
    myLinearDoubleKeyFrame2.KeyTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)
    myDoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames.Add(myLinearDoubleKeyFrame)
    myDoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames.Add(myLinearDoubleKeyFrame2)

    myDoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames.Duration = New Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(5000))

    Dim myStoryboard = New Storyboard()
    myStoryboard.Children.Add(myDoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames)

    Storyboard.SetTarget(myDoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames, Poly1)
    Storyboard.SetTargetName(myDoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames, Poly1.Name)
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(myDoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames, Opacity)

    myStoryboard.Begin()

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The target property is meant to be the **name** of the property to animate (or, more specifically, a PropertyPath, but that can be converted from a String).

Try the following:

```
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(myDoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames, "Opacity")
```